# MySQL Output parameter with asp.net and SqlDataSource control

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm in the process of switching my application from MSSQL to MYSQL. When I was using MSSQL, I retrieved the last auto increment value via

```
Private Sub dsImpoundInformation_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles dsImpoundInformation.Inserted
    _impoundId = e.Command.Parameters("impoundId").Value
End Sub

Private Sub dsImpoundInformation_Inserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs) Handles dsImpoundInformation.Inserting
    Dim impoundIdparam As New SqlClient.SqlParameter()
    impoundIdparam.ParameterName = "impoundId"
    impoundIdparam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
    impoundIdparam.DbType = DbType.Int32
    impoundIdparam.Value = 0
    e.Command.Parameters.Add(impoundIdparam)
End Sub
```

and

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO LotManager_impounds (accountId, truckId, createdBy, driver, locationId, dateArrived, towedFrom, reasonForImpound, reasonForImpoundOther, impoundCity, impoundCounty, timeOfImpound, dateDeemedAbandoned, ticketNumber) VALUES (@accountId,@truckId,@createdBy,@driver,@locationId,@dateArrived,@towedFrom,@reasonForImpound,@reasonForImpoundOther,@impoundCity,@impoundCounty,@timeOfImpound,@dateDeemedAbandoned,@ticketNumber); SET @impoundId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
```

Now when i try

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO LotManager_impounds (accountId, truckId, createdBy, driver, locationId, dateArrived, towedFrom, reasonForImpound, reasonForImpoundOther, impoundCity, impoundCounty, timeOfImpound, dateDeemedAbandoned, ticketNumber) VALUES (@accountId,@truckId,@createdBy,@driver,@locationId,@dateArrived,@towedFrom,@reasonForImpound,@reasonForImpoundOther,@impoundCity,@impoundCounty,@timeOfImpound,@dateDeemedAbandoned,@ticketNumber); SET @impoundId = LAST_INSERT_ID();"
```

i get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '0 = LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 1

And when i try:

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO LotManager_impounds (accountId, truckId, createdBy, driver, locationId, dateArrived, towedFrom, reasonForImpound, reasonForImpoundOther, impoundCity, impoundCounty, timeOfImpound, dateDeemedAbandoned, ticketNumber) VALUES (@accountId,@truckId,@createdBy,@driver,@locationId,@dateArrived,@towedFrom,@reasonForImpound,@reasonForImpoundOther,@impoundCity,@impoundCounty,@timeOfImpound,@dateDeemedAbandoned,@ticketNumber); SET impoundId = LAST_INSERT_ID();"
```

I get the error:

> Unknown system variable 'impoundId'

ultimately, I'm just trying to get the last auto increment value but there are other sections of my code in other applications that I plan on switching to MYSQL that depend on output parameters. I have't yet explored using stored procedures but at this time I would like to get this to work in a similar fashion to how I had it with MSSQL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I broke down and decided to use stored procedures. This is the best way to do it any ways and makes the code a lot cleaner. For anyone that's encountering this same problem my advice to you would be don't waste you time trying to make it work and just use a stored procedure.